# PDF with multible pages - pdfpages - captions

Tags: captions, pdf, pdfpages

I have a pdf-file that contains three pages.
Each page should be inserted on a separate page in my latex document.
I found the package pdfpages and tried to include this document by using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,bibliography=totoc,toc=listof,captions=tableheading,headings=small,listof=entryprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[language=autobib,
backend=biber]
{biblatex}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                         
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                            
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                                         
\usepackage{lmodern}                                                                
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}       
\usepackage{microtype}                                                              
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[format=hang,skip=2.5pt,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}                                                 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}                        


\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\includepdf[pages={1-3}, scale=0.6,frame, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, addtolist={1,figure,{Interview},Interview}]{interview.pdf} \captionof{figure}{Interview}

\end{document}
```

Notice: Please use a pdf file and rename it (--> interview.pdf) - unfortunately there is not a possibility to upload one!

Unfortunately the caption does not appear below the 1st and 2nd page - only below page no. 3 and then not exactly below the last page - it appears on the top at the following page.

Furthermore only the the number of the page where the caption appears is shown in the list-of-figures.

How can I reference these pages properly in the LOF (e.g. "1-3") and how can I put the caption below each page? (1st. page: "Interview" 2nd-3rd: "Interview (cont.)" ... ore something like this!)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example people can play with to try out solutions. This is much more useful than a mere fragment.

Comment: You need the package `kitchen-sink` since you already have all other packages. Please trim your preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is what you're after.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document} 
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=1,width=0.8\linewidth]{interview}
\caption{Interview}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\includegraphics[page=2,width=0.8\linewidth]{interview}
\caption{Interview (cont.)}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\includegraphics[page=3,width=0.8\linewidth]{interview}
\caption{Interview (cont.)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks quite good! I think there are square brackets missing: \caption[]{Interview (cont.)}. Thank You!

Comment: @TRJW Missing only if you don't want that caption text to end up in the list of figures, it wasn't entirely clear to me that that was what you wanted.